# Saving nested data in database

Tags: database, db2

I have some hierarchical data (currently 6 levels). Each level has different attributes.

I added a separate table for each level and added a foreign key for parent level in each table. But I don't know if it is the right approach.

```
Level1: id, ColA, ColB, ColC
Level2: id, ColD, ColE, ColF, level1_Id
Level3: id, ColG, ColH, level2_Id
Level4: id, ColI, ColJ, ColK, ColL, level3_Id
Level5: id, ColM, level4_Id
Level6: id, ColN, ColO, level5_Id
```

There will come additional levels in time. Therefore the design must be flexible so that I can add or remove some levels. Of course performance must be preserved.

Which design should I follow?

Comment: Which version of DB2?  Recent ones support the use of recursive queries, which support hierarchical models.  Also, what are your columns of data (how different are they in **intent**, not datatype)?  Can this (logically) be stored in a single table?  For a _known_ (at design time) number of levels, your initial approach would probably actually work fine.  You can run updates on the tables later, to add/remove levels.

Comment: @X-Zero I use DB2 9.7. The levels differ from each other, completeley different. In my case, it is not a good idea to store them in a flat table.

Comment: Then I'd probably stick with what you have.  If you have a known set of levels (like you appear to), then using a table structure for 'recursive' levels is unnecessary.  It's only when you head to arbitrary levels that things start getting 'interesting'.

Comment: @X-Zero It's even more important to establish which platform: z, i, or LUW.  The differences are larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid, it is not the best way, in the sense that it is not flexible enough to give you unlimited levels and performance.

This problem is called "Hierarchical Data Model", there are a few ways to implement it. Most portable format is called "Nested Sets" model. Other models are Adjacency Model, and the vendor specific models from Oracle and Microsoft.

Here is the stuff that can get you started

http://www.evanpetersen.com/item/nested-sets.html
http://www.sqlsummit.com/AdjacencyList.htm

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to clear the flexibility problem. If I have exactly 6 levels which design would you suggest?

Comment: I would still suggest the Nested Set model. You may spend a day or two to get it going and using it, but it's worthwhile a) you will learn to solve this problem which you will come across more than often b) you have built flexibility into the system.

Comment: Delete and Insert look like a real problem. What do you think about that?